# What is erasure

Tags: java, type-erasure

What is erasure and what is the restrictions of erasure on generics?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generics - type erasure - when and what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens)

Answer (score 3):

[Erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) is the result of types being used at compile time and not being present at runtime.  This is a common issue in Java Generics.  The main issue is that at runtime you are unable to determine the type a generic class contains.  For example if you have

```
ArrayList<Foo> t;
```

It is not possible to get the type, `Foo`, the `ArrayList` contains using reflection at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good explanation:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html