# How to create an ensureCapacity method that deals with Array Generics in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, generics

So, I am creating a generic data structure named "Sack". In this I add items to a sack, grab a random item, see if it's empty, or dump out its contents etc. Also I'm creating it to expand to hold as many items as needed.

I am currently working on a ensureCapacity method which it should ensure that the sack has the capacity for its parameter value, and if not, create a new underlying data structure for the sack that is one more than twice the current capacity of the sack.

I've tried numerous of methods of doing this, but I keep receiving an error. I'll drop down most of my code, but also the two methods I've tried and pointing out the errors I receive.

```
public class Sack<E>
{
 public static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
 private E [] elementData;
 private int size;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public Sack()
   {
     elementData = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
   }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Sack(int capacity)
{
    if(capacity < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity " + capacity);
    }
    this.elementData = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    if(size == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
 public E [] dump()
 {
   E [] E2 = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      elementData[i] = null;

   }
   size = 0;
    return E2;
}
```

First One: 
In this error, it's mainly when I run my tests saying that

AssertionFailedError: ensureCapacity is not working correctly

```
private void ensureCapacity(int capacity)
{
   if (size != capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity = (capacity * 2) + 1;
        elementData[capacity] = elementData[newCapacity];
    }
}
```

A little update, I will posts my tests. You guys can check it out and let me know, however I cannot modify my tests at all. Only my code. I commented the first line since that's where my error occurs.

```
@Test
public void testEnsureCapacity()
{
    assertEquals(2, ensureCapacity.getModifiers(), "ensureCapacity does not have the correct modifiers"); // My error occurs here currently. 
    try
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=10; ++i)
        {
            ensureCapacity.invoke(s, i);
            assertEquals(10, ((Object[])elementData.get(s)).length, "ensureCapacity is not working correctly (capacity changing unnecessarily)");
        }
        ensureCapacity.invoke(s, 11);
        assertEquals(21, ((Object[])elementData.get(s)).length, "ensureCapacity is not working correctly (capacity not increased correctly)");

        Random rand = new Random();
        int capacity = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
        s = new Sack<Integer>(capacity);
        for(int i=0; i<=capacity; ++i) {
            ensureCapacity.invoke(s, i);
            assertEquals(capacity, ((Object[])elementData.get(s)).length, "ensureCapacity is not working correctly (capacity changing unnecessarily)");
        }
        ensureCapacity.invoke(s, capacity+1);
        assertEquals(capacity*2+1, ((Object[])elementData.get(s)).length, "ensureCapacity is not working correctly (capacity not increased correctly)");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail("ensureCapacity is not working correctly");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, here's what the solution is to my question.

```
private void ensureCapacity(int capacity)
{
    if (elementData.length < capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity = elementData.length * 2 + 1;
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because of "Erasure" - ie. the generic types are for compile-time only, but are "erased" from the compiled byte-code.  This means that the run-time does not know which type "E" represents, so cannot create instances of (nor arrays of) any generic type.  (See also [What is erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891993/what-is-erasure) ).

So, you can replace that error line to create an Object array as you have done already :

```
E [] newList = (E[]) new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
```

But that's not ideal - much better is to create the arrays of the correct type straight off.  The workaround to do that is to modify your constructor to take an argument of the actual runtime type Class (I like calling this argument "clazz"), so you can keep that reference handy - so :

```
private Class<E> clazz;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Sack(Class<E> clazz, int capacity)
{
    if(capacity < 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("capacity " + capacity);
    }
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.elementData = (E[]) Array.newInstance(this.clazz, capacity);
}
```

and of course replace that error line with :

```
E [] newList = (E[]) Array.newInstance(this.clazz, capacity);
```

**EDIT FOR "First" AND UNIT-TEST:**

So in your unit-test - I assume "ensureCapacity" is a variable of type Method.
<s>That assert states that it is expecting two modifiers, but the actual value it finds in one.
I expect you will have covered modifiers in your class, but briefly you can consider that there are two "groups" of modifiers - "Access-Modifiers" and the rest  (ie "Non-Access-Modifiers") - see https://dzone.com/articles/all-about-java-modifier .</s>

As I mentioned, you have one modifier already on your ensureCapacity method - namely, the Access-Modifier "public".  So the assertion error that you're getting means that you are expected to have another (non-access) modifier alongside it.  I can only guess which that second modifier would be (again, that would have been covered in your class), but it will be one of those in the dzone article above - so read that article, and compare it to what you have been taught.

So something like :

```
private void ensureCapacity(int capacity)
{
   if (size > capacity)
   {
       int newCapacity = (capacity * 2) + 1;
       elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, let me clarify, the ensureCapacity method should ensure that the sack has the capacity for its parameter value, and if not, create a new underlying data structure for the sack that is one more than twice the current capacity of the sack.

Comment: My answer above was for the "Second".  Sorry, I do not understand the "First" issue "the modifiers are incorrect and that it is Expected: 2, and the Actual: 1".  The code looks fine to me, and the only modifier in that code is "public" which is valid.  Could you edit the question to add the unit test that produces those errors?

Comment: I will post my tests in order to clarify much more better.

Comment: I have updated my answer, that hopefully provides sufficient help for a way forward.  By the way, in addition should you have a "+1" in that first method?

Comment: Still receive the same error, I can't modify my tests. Only my code.

Comment: In your code, have you added one of the non-access modifiers to your function declaration of ensureCapacity ?

Comment: Alright I will. However it's on my first code, not second.

Comment: Thanks - but there's still only the one modifier "public".  Re-read my edit above, and the dzone article I linked to.

Comment: Thank you, I've read it all, but I don't think that is the problem. I believe the problem occurs within my code and how it is structured.

Comment: One of the non-access modifiers listed on that dzone page is "final" - so if you change your method declaration from "'public void ensureCapacity(int capacity)'" to "'public final void ensureCapacity(int capacity)'" how does your test go?

Comment: I receive the same error as I did in the beginning. The error although does not rely with that at all. I'm pretty sure it relies within inside that method itself.

Comment: My bad, you are right, the method should be private and not public. I will keep looking deeper into this.

Comment: My bad also - the getModifiers() method that the test calls does not return the count of the modifiers as I thought, but a value indicating all that are present - so 2 would indicate just one modifier.

Comment: and just confirming (on my system at least) the "`private`" should return 2, so should be getting past that initial test.  Incidentally, that "if" statement in the updated "First one" is redundant, since the same assignment to elementData is being performed on the next statement anyway.

Comment: I'm going to update it, if you have a solution on what I have right now. If you have any solutions on how to solve this, please try to answer the question again. What that method should do is ensure that the sack has the capacity for its parameter value, and if not, create a new underlying data structure for the sack that is one more than twice the current capacity of the sack.

Comment: Could you possibly rewrite that method in another answer on here so I could see it in more clarity.